# How render form on new page using React NavLink?

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-router

I have the following NavLink in my React Sidebar component that successfully links to an add-folder new page; however, I'm unable to render an AddFolder form on this new page (I've successfully tested that the AddFolder form renders in the Sidebar component, but that's not what I want). I've tried numerous things to resolve this, including using "component={AddFolder}", "render={={() => { return }}". Most recently I tried adding an onClick which doesn't work either.

```
            <section className="AddFolder_Section">
                <NavLink 
                    className="AddFolder_Button"
                    tag={Link}
                    to={'/add-folder'}
                    type='button'
                    onClick={() => this.AddFolder}
                >
                    Add Folder
                </NavLink>
            </section>
```

Are there pointers that you can give me on what might work here? Thank you.

Here are the entire contents of my sidebar.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { NavLink, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import NotesContext from './notesContext'
import AddFolder from './addFolder'
import './sidebar.css'

class Sidebar extends Component {
    static contextType = NotesContext
    render() {
        let notesContext = this.context
        const selectedFolder = this.props.match.params.folder_id || {}
        return (
            <section className="Sidebar">
                {notesContext.folders.map(folder => {
                    return(
                        <section key={folder.id} className={(selectedFolder && selectedFolder === folder.id)? "SelectedFolder": "Folder"}>
                            <NavLink className="Folder_Link" 
                                tag='button'
                                role='link'
                                to={'/folder/' + folder.id}>
                                {folder.name}
                            </NavLink>
                        </section>
                    )
                })}

                <section className="AddFolder_Section">
                    <NavLink 
                        className="AddFolder_Button"
                        tag={Link}
                        to={'/add-folder'}
                        type='button'
                        onClick={() => this.AddFolder}
                    >
                        Add Folder
                    </NavLink>
                    <Route
                        path='/add-folder'
                        render={(props) => 
                            <AddFolder
                                {...props}
                            />    
                        }
                    />  
                </section>
            </section>


        );
    }
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Comment: Hello there. Did you set the ```<Route/>``` for this ```NavLink```? Could you please post your Routes here as well? In order to render a component you should set you ```component``` or ```render={() => <SomeComponent/>}``` whithin your ```routes```.

Comment: Also, could you kindly confirm that you have set ```react-router``` ```react-router-dom``` in your ```app``` correctly, like wrapping the ```app``` with ```BrowserRouter```, for example?

Comment: This is actually the first question I've ever posted to StackOverflow. I haven't been able to figure out how to paste the contents of my entire file. To answer your ?s, I have tried adding a Route underneath the NavLink, to no avail (meaning I get a new blank page but the form is still not being rendered on the blank page). The route looked like this: <Route path='/add-folder' component={AddFolder}/>

Comment: Regarding confirming that I have set react-router etc... yes, this is working for all of the other components that I have.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question: `AddFolder` is your "form" component.

You need to first `import` your `AddFolder` component on the parent component that you want to render the form on.

`import AddFolder from '../somePath/AddFolder';`

Then on your `render()` function, place the `<Route>` and simply render the `AddFolder` component when you are on the `add-folder` path. Pass props if needed.

```
<Route
    path='/add-folder'
    render={(props) =>
        <AddFolder
            {...props}
        />
    }
/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I actually do have that import in my file. I have tried this same render without luck. I will try to figure out a way to post the entire contents of the file here.

Comment: I added the entire contents of my file in my question above. The render includes a return which includes a list of folders (using map) and then an Add Folder button section that includes a NavLink and a Route. I've tried many dfferent permutations for the AddFolder section -- 1) NavLink only, 2) Route only, 3) NavLink and Router within Router, 4) NavLink and Router within a Switch, 4) Use of Render with the Route, 5) Use of component with the Route.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had a typo in the Route defined in my App.js. I needed 'add-folder' instead of 'add_folder'. Now the Route in App works with the NavLink in Sidebar. Yeah!

Here is the App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import Header from './header.js'
import Main from './main.js'
import MainDetail from './mainDetail.js'
import Sidebar from './sidebar.js'
import SidebarDetail from './sidebarDetail.js'
import NotesContext from './notesContext'
import './App.css'
import config from './config'
import AddFolder from './addFolder'
import AddNote from './addNote'

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    folders: [],
    notes: [],
    error: null,
  };

  setData = (notes, folders) => {
    this.setState({
      notes,
      folders,
      error: null
    })
  }

  deleteNote = note_id => {
    fetch(config.API_ENDPOINT + "/notes/" + note_id, {
      method: 'DELETE',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => {
        const newNotes = this.state.notes.filter(note => note.id !== note_id)
        this.setState({
          notes: newNotes
        })
      })
  }

  addFolder = (name, id) => {
    this.setState({
      folders: [...this.state.folders, {name, id}]
    })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Promise.all([
      fetch(config.API_ENDPOINT + "/notes"),
      fetch(config.API_ENDPOINT + "/folders")
    ])
    .then(responses => {
      return Promise.all(responses.map(function (response) {
        return response.json();
      }));
    })
    .then(results => {
      this.setData(results[0], results[1])
    })
    .catch(error => this.setState({ error }))
  }

  render() {
    const contextValue = {
      notes: this.state.notes,
      folders: this.state.folders,
      deleteNote: this.deleteNote,
      addFolder: this.addFolder
    }

    //console.log(this.state.notes)
    return (
      <NotesContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
        <section className="App">
          <Switch>
            <Route
              exact path="/" 
              component={Header}
            />
            <Route 
              path="/folder/:folder_id" 
              component={Header}
            />
            <Route
              path="/note/:note_id" 
              component={Header}
            />
          </Switch>
          <section className="Section_Sidebar">
              <Switch>
                  <Route 
                    exact path="/" 
                    component={Sidebar}
                  />
                  <Route 
                    path="/folder/:folder_id" 
                    component={Sidebar}
                  />
                  <Route 
                    path="/note/:note_id" 
                    component={SidebarDetail}
                  />
              </Switch>
          </section>
          <section className="Section_Main">
              <Switch>
                <Route 
                  exact path="/" 
                  component={Main}
                  />
                <Route 
                  path="/folder/:folder_id" 
                  component={Main}
                />
                <Route 
                  path="/note/:note_id" 
                  component={MainDetail}
                />
                <Route 
                  path="/add-folder" 
                  component={AddFolder}
                />
                <Route 
                  path="/add-note" 
                  component={AddNote}
                />
              </Switch>
          </section>
        </section>
      </NotesContext.Provider>
    );
  } 
}

export default App;
```

This is the updated Sidebar.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { NavLink, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import NotesContext from './notesContext'
import AddFolder from './addFolder'
import './sidebar.css'

class Sidebar extends Component {
    static contextType = NotesContext
    render() {
        let notesContext = this.context
        const selectedFolder = this.props.match.params.folder_id || {}
        return (
            <section className="Sidebar">
                {notesContext.folders.map(folder => {
                    return(
                        <section key={folder.id} className={(selectedFolder && selectedFolder === folder.id)? "SelectedFolder": "Folder"}>
                            <NavLink className="Folder_Link" 
                                tag='button'
                                role='link'
                                to={'/folder/' + folder.id}>
                                {folder.name}
                            </NavLink>
                        </section>
                    )
                })}

                <section className="AddFolder_Section">
                    <NavLink 
                        className="AddFolder_Button"
                        tag={Link}
                        to={'/add-folder'}
                        type='button'
                    >
                        Add Folder
                    </NavLink>
                    
                </section>
            </section>


        );
    }
}

export default Sidebar;
```